# Workflows Stopping and detaching themselves from Items : AutoStart Workflow: System.ArgumentException

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, error, email, workflow-activity

We have a number of worflows on numerous list's, and they have recently detached them selves from the list , by that i mean that they no longer appear in the workflows area. Also they have stopped and not sent the emails that we built into them.

I looked in the Log and found this error: **AutoStart Workflow: System.ArgumentException: New instances of this workflow template are currently disallowed**.

From time to time they will also duplicate.

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this as it is a urgent and serious issue?

Comment: Hi Thomas, please correct me if I have misunderstand your question - Your workflows for many different list recently just disappear from the workflow folder and before that, they actually duplicate themselves causing the error to occur.

Comment: ran into this problem today and also looking for a solution. On a list the button to run a workflow manually has dissapeared. The workflow should run automatically when something is entered into a list.

Comment: Our users reported this on SharePoint 2007 too. Looking into the issue as well. Workflow still associated, new instances allowed but still the message in ULS says the contrary - "New instances ... disallowed"

Comment: Going to try increasing batch size and threshold

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue recently. I found out that When workflow instance that attached with list, workflow has multiple version. You can check it from `workflow settings` in the ribbon of the list.

When I go deep down I found that those previous version have disabled new instance. you can check it in `add or remove workflow` section in `workflow settings`.

When We try to auto start workflow, It try to start all instance. In my case, I complete all other instance and remove them to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Transaction Log from Farm ConfigDB. This exception rises when no space inside Log or Disk. Truncate Log in SQL Server.